# How to store groups of doubles using structures and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, struct, double, structure

Hey so Im just looking for advice (Im new to C) on how to store groups of 4 doubles. Is there an array where each array element will hold a another array of doubles? What would this look like. Thanks!

Comment: The question includes insufficient detail for making a recommendation. What is the intended use of these? What are the "groups" of doubles?

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can ! 
The best way would be to use `structures`, and to declare an array of structures.
Here is an example :

```
struct doublesContainers{
    double value1;
    double value2;
    double value3;
    double value4;
}
```

And after that declare an array of `doublesContainers` : `doublesContainers myArray[100];`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an array where each array element will hold a another array of doubles?

Yes - you're asking for a 2D array (which in C is declared as an array of arrays):

```
double arr[N][4]; // where N is the number of groups you want.
```

You'd assign each value as

```
arr[i][j] = some_value; // where 0 <= i < N and 0 <= j < 4
```

If you don't know `N` ahead of time, you can allocate the array at runtime using one of two methods.  You can either use a *variable-length* array (only available since the 1999 standard, and optional as of the 2011 standard):

```
size_t n;
n = get_size_of_array(); // stand-in for whatever code gets the array size
double arr[n][4];
```

or you can use dynamic memory allocation:

```
size_t n;
n = get_size_of_array();
double (*arr)[4] = malloc( sizeof *arr * n ); // yes, this is ugly.  Welcome to programming in C.
```

If you use dynamic memory allocation, you'll need to deallocate the array when you're done with it:

```
free( arr );
```

If `N` can be large, use dynamic memory allocation instead of the VLA.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can declare a two-dimensional array as for example

```
enum { N = 100 };
double a[N][4];
```

To access an element of the array you can use an expression with the subscript operator as

```
a[i][j]
```

where `i` is in the range `[0, N)` and `j` in the range `[0, 4)`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    double a[N][4] = { { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 }, { 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 7.0 } };

    printf( "a[1][2] = %f\n", a[1][2] );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
a[1][2] = 7.000000
```

Or you can define a structure that contains a one-dimensional array and then declare an array of structures as for example

```
struct Tuple 
{
    double values[4];
};
enum { N = 100 };

struct Tuple a[N];
```

To access an element of the structure that is in turn an element of the array you can use the following expression

```
a[i].values[j]
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Tuple 
{
    double values[4];
};

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    struct Tuple a[N] = { { { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 } }, { { 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 7.0 } } };

    printf( "a[1].values[2] = %f\n", a[1].values[2] );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
a[1].values[2] = 7.000000
```

Take into account that the compiler can support a variable length arrays. In this case you can calculate the size of the array at run-time instead of using a predefined constant expression as `N` in the code snippets above.

Answer (score 0):

As @cocool97 said using structures is a good way to go. In addition, you can do a structure with an array of 4 doubles.

```
struct four_doubles {
  double tupple[4];
};
int sum(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
  struct four_doubles s;
  s.tupple[0] = a;
  s.tupple[1] = b;
  s.tupple[2] = c;
  s.tupple[3] = d;
  return s.tupple[0] + s.tupple[1] + s.tupple[2] + s.tupple[3];
}
```

If you need a list of them:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int  main() {
  struct four_doubles* list = malloc(64 * sizeof(struct four_doubles));
  if (list == NULL) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }  // Possible out of memory
}
```

You can also do an array of pointers to an array of four doubles, see @Vlad-from-Moscow answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using pointers. Pointers are dynamically allocated and can be closely managed to maintain efficiency. Here is some example code of how to accomplish this task with pointers:

```
double** dblPtr = malloc(sizeof(double*)*numberOfDoubleGroupsToStore);
int i = 0;
for (int i; i < numberOfDoubleGroupsToStore; i++)
{
    dblPtr[i] = malloc(sizeof(double)*4);
}
```

As always with pointers make sure to manage your memory and free your variables when they are no longer necessary to your code!